# "Manage External Users" option missing in Permission Set

Tags: permission-sets

I'm trying to make a Permission Set for the "Manage External Users" setting, however I'm not seeing it listed in the "System Permissions" section of the Permission Set.

It's for a "Company Communities" license type. I'm fairly certain this license type should have access to that setting, because their Profile is the same license type but has the option. I just don't want to enable the setting for the entire Profile, hence the Permission Set need.

Do I need to enable something else on the Permission Set first, before it appears?

Thank you!

Comment: This option is under `App Permissions --> Partner Relationship Management`. Don't you see it there as well?

Comment: Thank you very much @JayantDas !
I thought I looked there already but I must have just glossed over it.

Sorry for the stupid question and thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As posted by Jayant Das:

> This option is under App Permissions --> Partner Relationship
>   Management. Don't you see it there as well?